# ActionScript Effects using Tweener?

Tags: actionscript-3, tweener

HI,

I want to implement tweener effects in my application, but I have a rectangle,

```
shape = new Shape();
shape.graphics.beginFill(0xF9F9F9); 
shape.graphics.drawRect(200,80,700,450);
shape.graphics.endFill();
account_label.label ="Accounts";
account_label.setPosition(200,530);
account_label.width =140;
personal_details_label.label ="Personal Details";
personal_details_label.setPosition(340,530);
personal_details_label.width=180;
```

the above code shows my rectangle and two buttons,

Intially Accounts Form was selected by default, when i click PersonalDetails button i have to show the screen change effect (From Right to Left that means Personal DetailsForm is moving from right to left ) within that rectangle. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of [tweensy](http://code.google.com/p/tweensy), but you can do this with most tweening engines easily

```
Tweensy.to(shape, {x:-100}, 2.0);
 Tweensy.onComplete = animationComplete; //optional
```

The important part to consider when working with animations is timing. Either disable buttons or setup a proper fallbacks. The animations can take a few seconds and if the user can restart the animation, or if objects aren't cleared or initialized properly you can run into some issues.